# How to transfer settings of extension "Multi-Account Containers" in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I use extension of Firefox: "[Multi-Account Containers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multi-account-containers/)".
In this extension I have several created containers related with some sites.
I need to transfer this settings to Firefox in my another computer.
How to transfer this settings without synchronization of Firefox account?

P.S. I use Linux Mint 19.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Linux, just copy `~/.mozilla/firefox/the_name_of_your_profile/containers.json` to your new firefox profile. (Don't forget to install Multi-account containers in the new browser first.)

You can find out your current the_name_of_your_profile by visiting

```
about:support
```

right in the firefox url field and find **Profile Directory** in that page.

Answer (score 0):

Latest version of Firefox can sync containers. Yeayyy

In your case you can copy the containers.js file and storage file to the new computer. However it causes problems as other PC’s storage gets deleted. Sync is the safest option.

Comment: syncing doesn't seem to work and `~/.mozilla/firefox/xxxxx.default/browser-extension-data/@testpilots/containers.js` seems to have been replaced by `storage.js.migrated` which is not altered when one modifies one's containers settings.  I'm still trying to figure this out by following some info [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/8qfxo7/firefox_containers_export/)

Comment: Wait! Sync does work *if*, critically, you 'enable sync' within the containers preference settings.  This option is now given with fresh installs if you begin the set up process for containers.

Comment: Also syncing can be self-hosted, thanks to [syncserver](https://github.com/mozilla-services/syncserver).